# Scale Function Returns: Error in FUN(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)), ...)

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization

Trying to train a NeuralNet but I can't normalize my data.

Defining Max and Mins for scaling this is working fine.

```
 maxs <- apply(tour_weahter_data, 2, max) 
 mins <- apply(tour_weahter_data, 2, min)
```

Here is the data I'am trying to scale:

```
head(tour_weahter_data)
Start Time Starting          Station ID Duration  Distance Temperatur Humidity
    1 2016-07-07 13:00:00                3063       12  578.7915         18       72
    2 2016-07-07 13:00:00                3040       10 1262.4654         18       72
    3 2016-07-07 13:00:00                3063       19 1660.0441         18       72
    4 2016-07-07 13:00:00                3018       10  907.1427         18       72
    5 2016-07-07 13:00:00                3076       10 1004.5161         18       72
    6 2016-07-07 13:00:00                3034        4  448.0982         18       72
```

This is the call to the function:

```
 scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(tour_weahter_data, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))
```

This is the Error Message I get:

> Error in FUN(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)), ...) : 
>   non-numeric argument to binary operator
>   In addition: Warning message:
>     In scale.default(tour_weahter_data, center = mins, scale = maxs -  :
>   NAs introduced by coercion

Is there a problem with my data or am I using the function incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `scale` with `numeric` variables, so you must use it only with numeric variables.

Here's an approach using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

vars_scale <- tour_weahter_data %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  colnames()


scale_min_max <- function(x) scale(x, center = min(x), scale = max(x) - min(x))


tour_weahter_data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars_scale, scale_min_max)

## A tibble: 6 x 7
#  Start[,1] Time_Starting       Station_ID[,1] Duration[,1]
#      <dbl> <dttm>                       <dbl>        <dbl>
#1       0   2016-07-07 13:00:00          0.776        0.533
#2       0.2 2016-07-07 13:00:00          0.379        0.4  
#3       0.4 2016-07-07 13:00:00          0.776        1    
#4       0.6 2016-07-07 13:00:00          0            0.4  
#5       0.8 2016-07-07 13:00:00          1            0.4  
#6       1   2016-07-07 13:00:00          0.276        0    
## ... with 3 more variables: Distance[,1] <dbl>,
##   Temperatur[,1] <dbl>, Humidity[,1] <dbl>
```

Comment: Yeah the DateTime was the Problem. Thank you i just did it like this, excluding the First two cols. Now it works.
scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(tour_weahter_data[,3:6], center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))
Any Idea on how i can add the other two cols back in?

Comment: You can bind them with `cbind`. For example `cbind(tour_weahter_data[,1:2], scaled)`

Comment: ok that worked but can i be sure that i bound the data correctly meaning the same rows together again?

Comment: @JensKrüger Since the functions you're using are vectorized, they won't change row orders, so don't worry about this. But you can set `rownames` and check it.